# How does MediaWiki redirect pages?

Tags: php, mediawiki

Current versions of MediaWiki have the front page accessible via

```
http://www.example.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

Instead of the older version of

```
http://www.example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
```

That second URL is literally how the PHP script would be called in most casual web apps, but the above URL is cleaner and more desirable. Now, I can see how that could easily be converted with an Apache mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php/(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1
```

But there's no htaccess file in the default MediaWiki setup. So how are they doing the redirect?

Comment: Okay, so after some testing with my own Apache server, it looks like requesting "/helloworld.php/foo/bar" is the same as requesting "/helloworld.php". But, requesting "helloworld.html/foo/bar" is not the same as "/helloworld.html" (former gives a 404). So there's something special about PHP files being served from Apache. That seems rather fragile to me; guess I should ask another question about that then...

Comment: shouldn't be anything special. does the file "/helloworld.html" exist? if not there would be a 404 error. if the file does exist, it should load the html file.

Comment: In my sample, "/helloworld.html" exists. When testing on my local server, I get a proper load (HTTP 200) for a request of "/helloworld.html", and a 404 response for "/helloworld.html/foobar" or "/helloworld.html/foobar/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what they are doing, but there no need to redirect using a .htaccess. the page index.php is found and that script is what is loaded. index.php just gets $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and parses that into the query string.

Comment: +1 I'm fairly sure that, or the very near equivalent, is exactly what they're doing.

Comment: I've done it in the past so I know it works. Just not feeling up to searching through mediawiki to find where they are doing it to confirm it.

Comment: So, when apache gets a request for "/wiki/index.php/anything", it knows that "index.php" is the file because of the period? So if someone (unwisely) named a folder with a period in the middle, the contents of it would be unable to be served via apache, since it would always assume the folder was the target file, and the rest was the query string?

Comment: the period has nothing do to with it. As apache is traversing the requested url, it starts at the beginning (using your example of "/wiki/index.php/anything") and looks in the document root for a file/folder named "wiki", folder found so it continues on, looks for a file/folder named "index.php", file found so it stops and loads that file.

Answer (score 1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo